# Reading Raster Data with ArcGIS tools in C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcobjects, c#

I have a raster data layer as IRasterLayer and I am using C# SDK of ArcGIS. Here is the [IRasterLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRasterLayer_Interface/001200000p9n000000/).

1. I want to access all the cells
2. I want to edit cell values.

After all i need how can i read the raster data. Where will I get the values in `IRasterLayer`

Answer (score 1):

To access the pixel data with IRaster2, IRasterCursor, and IPixelBlock3, et al:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_access_pixel_data_using_a_raster_cursor/00010000000t000000/

Looks like you could also use IRawBlocks and IRasterBandCollection:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_access_pixel_data_using_the_RawBlocks_object/000100000022000000/